# HelloWeb: HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, http-status-code-404

I am new to Netbeans and I am trying to deploy the simple "HelloWeb" project from this [Netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html#setting). I am using NetBeans 8.0.2. I have deployed the app and am certain the application has been deployed based on the glassfish server console output which is shown below...

[image]

I can clearly see in the admin console that the application has been deployed, as can be seen below...

[image]

When I try to click "Launch", I am presented with this page, which looks like it deployed to 2 different ports.

[image]

When I click either link, I get the 404 error message like below...

[image]

Everything seems to be deployed correctly, so why would I get this 404 error message? Is 404 always shown if something is crashing behind the scenes? Where is the best place to start debugging something like this in Netbeans?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your project contain `index.jsp` **OR** `index.html`?

Comment: When I created the initial project it was index.html. I deleted that and manually created the index.jsp based on the instructions in the first "Note" section from the tutorial.

Comment: Try [http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb](http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb)

Comment: Sorry for delay in response, I already tried that before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

The project deployed locally gets deployed on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).

In your case the project is deployed at http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb.

You can also access it using http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWeb

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify your index.jsp as welcome file within *web.xml*?

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
        index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```